# ggplot alpha levels appear different on fill and border of points (ringing artefact)

Tags: r, ggplot2, transparency, visualization, alpha

I am plotting many points using ggplot with a constant  transparency value for all points.

What I find is that the circular points have a more transparent fill than their individual border, so that the borders are noticeably brighter than their fill (I'm plotting light circles on a dark background), i.e. there seems to be a ringing artefact.

[The effect is that they look like rings rather than semi-transparent circles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k20kW.png)

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame( x = sample(1:100,2000, replace=T), 
                    y = sample(1:100,2000, replace=T) )
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=0.2, color="dodgerblue", fill="dodgerblue", size=4) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black', colour = 'black'))
```

I'm not sure why it does this, so information as to why this occurs would be great.

Possible solutions would be to make the border and fill the same transparency, or to make the border 100% transparent (setting the border to say, the background colour, would ruin the visuals when points overlap). I'm not sure how to do either of these.

Comment: Please sufficient amount of  a dataset using `dput` that can be used for testing.

Comment: @42 Just added sufficient code to fully reproduce issue.

Comment: @baptiste Setting `colour = NA` in place of the current `color="dodgerblue"` makes the points entirely disappear, not just the border. Could you give an example of how to apply your second suggestion?

Comment: Added a simpler solution, based just on using shape=16 - is that not what you are after? That one also renders correctly in the RStudio plot preview window.

Comment: I think my answer should be checked as the correct answer as the one checked now didn't really resolve the OP's problem for me...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that you want disks with constant colour & opacity simplest thing to do that fixed it for me, also in the RStudio plot preview window is just to use option `shape=16` :

```
data <- data.frame( x = sample(1:100,2000, replace=T), 
                y = sample(1:100,2000, replace=T) )
ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=0.2, color="dodgerblue", size=5, shape=16) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black', colour = 'black'))
```

[image]

Alternatively, `shape=21` and a 100% semitransparent fill with 
`fill=adjustcolor("dodgerblue",alpha.f=0)` also works:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + 
     geom_point(alpha=0.2, fill=adjustcolor("dodgerblue",alpha.f=0), size=5, shape=21) +
     theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black', colour = 'black'))
```

[image]

Using `stroke=0` as suggested in the currently accepted answer doesn't seem to resolve the problem entirely for me (ringing effect goes away a little bit but not entirely, this is on Windows at least) :

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point(alpha=0.2, colour="dodgerblue", fill="dodgerblue", stroke=0,  size=5) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black', colour = 'black'))
```

[image]

Comment: Agreed hehe :-)

Comment: Agreed. Accepted this answer

Answer (score 5):

Changing stroke to 0 seems to have hte desired result:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=0.2, colour="dodgerblue", fill=mycol, stroke=0,  size=5) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black', colour = 'black'))
```

Comment: This appears to reduce the size of the markers slightly, however the "ring" effect is still clear to me. There is distinctly a border on the points. I am after just a semi-transparent dot.

Comment: I'm not seeing any ring. I'm wondering if you are seeing an artifact of your viewer or an optical illusion. Have you tried saving to a vector graphic file format and blowing it up?

Comment: Great point. I don't see the issue after saving as a PDF and viewing that, either with or without a `stroke` argument. I was using the inbuilt RStudio viewer, and the issue persists when saving as a PNG. However, due to the large number of points in my actual data and the inefficiency of vector graphics for points, I would like to be able to save as e.g. PNG without having this issue. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Tried it with png format (which one would expect to be "less efficient" than a vector format.). Still no ring. The pixelation is a bit prominent, but you can alter the resolution to account for whatever

Comment: That's odd that it doesn't appear for you. There is a link to a small example image in my original post. Regarding graphics formats, my understanding is that raster formats scale better for large scatter plots compared to vector formats (although I can't find a good source for that right now). This seems to be the case in my own experience, especially for file size, however I could be mistaken.

Comment: Saving the plot as a png with a higher dpi has solved the issue after all. So it appears that the cause was just low res blending between the edge of the marker and the background colour. This is the case using `stroke=0` or not, although looks better with `stroke=0` in my opinion. I'll add an answer to provide this solution. I can't upvote @42's answer as my rep is too low, but I'll come back and do so once it's high enough. Thanks for your help, @42 !

Comment: @conor: You _can_ checkmark it. It's your question.

Comment: I'm not clear on the SO protocol. Your answer posted here didn't solve the original post, although it was helpful and the discussion did lead to its solution. Should I accept your answer, or the direct answer that I've added (which I have to wait 2 days for)?

Comment: The protocol is that you get to make any decision you want.

Comment: In that case, going off the checkmark alt-text "Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or _was the most helpful in finding your solution_ (click again to undo)" I'll accept your answer. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: This answer for me didn't resolve the problem, whereas my solution below worked - maybe my answer should be checked as the correct answer?

Comment: @TomWenseleers : Graphics devices may vary depending on operating systems. This solution worked for the OP 3 years ago. I had tested it on a Mac. Now these many years later, after testing it still works on a Linux box at least to the extent of solving the display issues on an Rstudio plot window. Perhaps you are using Windoze?

Comment: Yes I'm using Windows and for me when I try to use stroke=0 the issue gets a little better but doesn't entirely disappear. I'd be keen to know if using the solution to use shape=16 works well cross-platform...

Comment: @42- : I've added some screenshots (obtained with the standard PNG export from the RStudio plot window) to show that your answer with stroke=0 doesn't seem to work 100% (on Windows at least)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Tom Wenseleers solution (accepted) is better than the below.

After discussion with @42, the solution is that the PNG default had resolution low enough that at the border between a marker and the image background there was a blending artifact (might not be the right terminology).

Increasing the dpi solves the issue, and adding `stroke=0` looks a bit better.

```
ggsave("plot.png",
  ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=0.2, color="dodgerblue", fill="dodgerblue", size=4, stroke=0) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black', colour = 'black')),
  dpi=1200)
```

Comment: Stiil the effect for me doesn't go away entirely then - my answer below by contrast gets rid of the ringing effect completely (just using shape=16)!