# How to change alpha in geom_sf?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

Is there a way to change `alpha` with `geom_sf`? This example is from the examples in `?geom_sf`. I tried adding `alpha=.2` but it seems to ignore that aesthetic, although `alpha` is an accepted aesthetic for `geom_line`. It does not ignore alpha for the `fill` - which in this example is `NA` though.

```
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, proj.4 4.9.3
library(ggplot2)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
nc_3857 <- sf::st_transform(nc, "+init=epsg:3857")

ggplot() + geom_sf(data = nc) + 
  geom_sf(data = nc_3857, colour = "red", fill = NA, alpha = 0.2)
```

Comment: From what I understand, it was a [deliberate design decision](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1371) for `alpha` to affect `fill` but not `colour` aesthetics in geoms with both. It **is** possible to rewrite your own geom with a different behaviour in `GeomSf`'s `draw_panel` function, but I wouldn't recommend it. When you have adjacent polygons, the overlapping lines will have a higher cumulative alpha than the lines at the outer boundaries.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's called an outline. I never worked with maps and the result is not quite pretty but I hope this is still helpful and this could help you more:
[ggplot2: different alpha values for border and filling of geom_point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661304/ggplot2-different-alpha-values-for-border-and-filling-of-geom-point)

```
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, proj.4 4.9.3
library(ggplot2)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
nc_3857 <- sf::st_transform(nc, "+init=epsg:3857")

ggplot() + geom_sf(data = nc) + 
  geom_sf(data = nc_3857, color=alpha("red",0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: how does that work when you have multiple groups and need to use aes(color =)?

Comment: Not sure I understand but you can have different aes() for each layer.

Answer (score 0):

Also alpha, can be clashing with other packages, i would recommend to specify which package you are using. In my case I had to

> color = scales::alpha('#c55252', 0.3)