# R ggplot2: How to draw geom_points that have a solid color and a transparent stroke and are colored depending on color?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a scatter plot where every point gets a sphere. Both the dot and its sphere are colored according to some column values.

A minimal example that shows what I want:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(vcd) # only needed for example dataset
ggplot(Arthritis, aes(x = ID, y = Age)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color=Sex), size=10, alpha=.3) + 
    geom_point(aes(color=Treatment), size=3)
```

[image]

The problem with this "solution" is that using two `geom_point` layers seems to mess up the legend. I guess it would also make much more sense to only have one `geom_point` layer and use a shape that also adds a stroke, so something like this:

```
ggplot(Arthritis, aes(x = ID, y = Age)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color=Sex, fill=Treatment), shape=21, size=5, stroke=5)
```

[image]
Here the legend makes way more sense, however, I can not figure out how to make the stroke transparent. This is important because you just can not see anything anymore when points overlap.

Answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39661751/7019073) do not solve my problem, because they use a constant color and thus can use the function `alpha`. However, I can not figure out if and how to use this with colors that depend on the data.

TL;DR: How can I draw `geom_points` that have a solid color and a transparent stroke but not constant colors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track to recognize that you can use the function `alpha()`, and have realized that you cannot just put `alpha()` within `aes()`.  You can, however, pass `alpha()` as the `values=` argument within any `scale_*` functions.  Here's an example using `mtcars`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  geom_point(
    aes(color=factor(cyl), fill=factor(carb)),
    shape=21, size=4, stroke=4) +
  scale_color_manual(values=alpha(rainbow(3), 0.2))
```

[image]

One problem with that is those big black lines around the "`factor(carb)` legend don't sit well with me.  Super ew.  You can get rid of them using the `guides()` function and using `override.aes=` to specify what you want shown there and what to replace it with.  In this case, you can set the `color=NA` to override the inherited aesthetic to be transparent (leaving only the `fill=` part).

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  geom_point(
    aes(color=factor(cyl), fill=factor(carb)),
    shape=21, size=4, stroke=4) +
  scale_color_manual(values=alpha(rainbow(3), 0.2)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes = list(color=NA))) +
  labs(color="cyl", fill="carb")
```

[image]

BTW, there's no simple way to place the stroke "behind" the fill part for `geom_point`.  You can probably write your own custom stat/geom for doing that, but `geom_point` is always drawn with fill first, then stroke.

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way round this is to make it so that the larger transparent circles aren't points at all, but filled circles. That way you can use the `fill` aesthetic to label them. This uses `geom_circle` from `ggforce`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(vcd)
library(ggforce)

ggplot(Arthritis) + 
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = ID, y0 = Age, r = 2, fill = Sex), alpha = .3, colour = NA) +
  geom_point(aes(x = ID, y = Age, color = Treatment), size = 3) + 
  coord_equal() + 
  scale_color_discrete(h = c(350, 190))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Or make a second color scale!

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(vcd) 
#> Loading required package: grid
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(Arthritis, aes(x = ID, y = Age)) + 
  ## removing stroke so it does not have this awkward border around it
  geom_point(aes(color=Sex), size=10, alpha=.3, stroke = 0) +
  new_scale_color()+
  geom_point(aes(color=Treatment), size=3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>