# Using a custom function for alpha aesthetic in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to be able to map the alpha values of the points (and lines) using a  conditional mapping in a custom function. The motivation behind this is to decrease the clutter in the portion of the dataset which isn't really interesting for the purpose of this graphic.

I know I can do a direct alpha scaling i.e. `geom_point(aes(alpha = avg.expression))` but I need symmetric scaling around 0, so both extremes have higher alpha and middle values are more transparent. I want to be able to emphasise variables that respond in a decreasing or increasing fashion to different treatments.

It was difficult to create a minimal working example to recreate this problem but I believe the following comes close:

```
set.seed(42)
ids <-stringi::stri_rand_strings(100, 5, pattern = "[A-Z]")
df <- data.frame(id = sample(ids, size = 500, replace = T), 
                 exp = rnorm(500, 0, 2), 
                 class = sample(LETTERS[1:6], size = 500, replace = T),
                 type = sample(1:2, size = 500, replace = T))
alpha.func <- function(n){
  print(n)
  n[abs(n) <= 1] <- 0
  n[abs(n) > 1 & abs(n) <= 2] <- 0.1
  n[abs(n) > 2 & abs(n) <= 4] <- 0.25
  n[abs(n) > 4] <- 0.75
  print(n)
}
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = class, y = exp, color = as.factor(type), group = id)) + 
  geom_point(aes(alpha = alpha.func(exp)))+ 
  geom_line(aes(alpha = alpha.func(exp)))
```

This example differs from the data I am working with in a couple of subtle but essential ways:

1. The data I am working on have a lot of more rows
2. Majority of the data expression values are between [-1, 1], which make that range extremely cluttered
3. The `class` variables are better connected to each other, such that most `id`s have more than 3-4 different `exp` values for different `classes`.

The interesting thing here is that if I look at the output from `alpha.func` I see 3 pairs of input-output. I would have expected 2, one for `geom_point` and one for `geom_line`. I am under the impression that there are several layers that are overlaid hence the alpha levels are not as to be expected.

If I plot this with the actual data I am working on, I get something like this

[image]

As you can see, the middle is far from being transparent, so something in this logic isn't working right.

Is it possible to achieve what I am going for here? Considering the flexibility that ggplot2 library provides, I feel there should be a way to do this.

Comment: When I run your code I get a different plot from those you show, and the alpha does seem to reduce in the centre - so I think your logic is probably OK.  If the charts above are based on a much bigger dataset, it might be that you need to reduce alpha a lot more, as lots of overlaid semi-transparent lines quickly build up to an effective solid colour.

Comment: The shape of the points in the plot you show is also different from the one generated with your code. I believe that you used 'shape = 21' to create your plot which creates a circle that has both a 'fill' and a 'colour' (i.e. the circle's border). In that case the alpha will only affect the fill. The easiest solution here is to not use shape = 21. If you want to have transparency on both the point's fill and colour see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381684/ggplot-alpha-levels-appear-different-on-fill-and-border-of-points

Comment: @AndrewGustar you're correct that's not the plot from the example, rather from the actual data. The example data does have some transparency but if I set the alpha for values in `-1 < n < 1` range to zero, I still see them, which implies that there are some other layers in play.